# Visual Studio Black Background?

Tags: visual-studio

I watch a lot of tutorials on the web, expesially ASP.NET tutorials - And constantly notice that everyone seems to have VS set with a black background and yellow/white text?

Why is this?  and how can I set up my version to look like it?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is [Rob Conery's TextMate](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDQQjBAwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstudiostyl.es%2Fschemes%2Fwekeroad-ink&ei=GQ50T8e2CYuXhQe9hsinBQ&usg=AFQjCNEYAx3Zh4jt6G-IGSGtW_3e8L3NZA&sig2=3y3DhqUpktEX1SCZ34dQ5A) theme that you want.

After Download in Studio ... Tools > Import & export settings and follow the wizard.

Share and enjoy!

Edit: Link updated

Comment: The "Rob Conery's TextMate" link is broken.

Comment: Hey @DanielElliott where is alternate link?

Answer (score 12):

For VS2012 : 
if you want to simply change the default black and white background then ; 
Go to Tools ->Options -> Environment -> General. 
Right side pan, you you will see Color theme drop down;select Dark or light  in order to get basic black and white background.

if you want to change default color,Font or Font size then you select ; 
Tools ->Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Answer (score 11):

Now, Visual Studio 2012 supports black theme.
To change to black theme :

> Tools -> Options -> Visual Experience -> Color theme

Comment: It's actually here (vs 2017):  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Color Theme -> Dark

Answer (score 7):

Check out shanselmans [blog article about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx), he lists quite a few of them, so pick one you like. Personally, I've got the Monaco font installed, and I love it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I'm giving the below a run now :)

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2017 you can do the following:

> Tools -> Options.. -> Environment -> General -> Color theme -> Dark -> OK

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it easier to read, and the colors can have more subtle hues and convey more meaning for me.

I used this scheme to start with: https://web.archive.org/web/20080116232122/http://www.agileprogrammer.com/dotnetguy/archive/2006/09/07/19030.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by taking visual studio tools - > options - >  font and colors and set what ever you want in font and text.

If you want some background image  means  : [try this tool](http://www.slickedit.com/content/view/441)

Answer (score 1):

Go to VS -> Tools -> Options. 
It has list of settings you can change. 
For changing color; look left side pane and select **Fonts and color**. 
You also can change default Item foreground and item background color as your wish from right side pane.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2015, go to tools>>options>>environment>>general>>dark
That's the theme I see most people use, and it feels much better on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Select : Tools > Options > General > Color Theme > Dark

You can also change the font by selecting :

Select : Tools > Options > General > Fonts and Colors > ...

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Color theme(from dropdown select): > Blue
```